# Is Ideal gas with $n\gg n_Q$ (Quantum) concentration effectivly at $T = 0$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, ideal-gas

For ideal gas with identical spin-½ fermions the fermi energy is:
$${\epsilon_{\text{f}}={\frac {\hbar ^{2}}{2m_{0}}}\left({\frac {3\pi ^{2}N}{V}}\right)^{2/3}}$$

and so we can write:$$\frac{\epsilon_f}\tau = \frac{1}{4\pi} \frac{2\pi\hbar^2}{m\tau} \left(\frac{3\pi^2N}{V}\right)^\frac{2}{3}=\frac{(3\pi^2)^\frac{2}{3}}{4\pi} \left(\frac{n}{n_Q}\right)^\frac{2}{3}$$

where $n=\frac{N}{V}$, the quantum concentration is $n_Q = \left(\frac{m\tau}{2\pi\hbar^2}\right)^\frac{3}2$ and $\tau = k_bT$ (Boltzmann's constant times temperature)

And so if the gas cocentration is big enough, meanning $\frac{n}{n_Q}\gg1$ then its clear $\ \ \frac{\epsilon_f}\tau\gg1\ $ which means all our thermal properties act as if T goes to zero.

This derivation seems off to me. is it wrong? am i missing somthing? If not why would higher concentrations of gas would act as if $T$ goes to zero?

Comment: $\tau$ is not defined.

Comment: Presumably $\tau=k_B T$ where $k_B$ is Boltzmann's constant? If so OP should edit this in.

Answer (score 1):

The Fermi energy is the energy of the highest occupied/lowest unoccupied single particle state. For fixed volume, additional particles in the ground state go into the lowest unoccupied state increasing the Fermi energy, as you demonstrate. A temperature $T$ much less than the Fermi energy can only excite particles within roughly $k_B T$ of the Fermi surface. So as the concentration increases, the fraction of the total number of particles that can be excited is reduced, and that is what your equations are telling you.